# Blazor bind to update UI when callback changes property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

Using Blazor, how can the displayed text update when the `Result` property is modified by the callback function?

```cs
<p>The current value is: @Result </p>

@code {
    private string Result { get; set; } = "";

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        OtherCode.OnResultChangedCB += (string? newResult) => Result = newResult ?? "None";
        base.OnInitialized();
    }
}
```

Comment: Invoke `StateHasChanged()` after the callback function execution.

Comment: What is `OtherCode`? What's the actual signature of `OnResultChangedCB` ? How is it triggered? Blazor doesn't use .NET events. That's why you don't see `+=` in the docs and tutorials. The events mentioned in the docs are DOM events or component callbacks. Nothing in the code you posted triggers `OnResultChangedCB`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't think that information matters for this particular question?  `OtherCode` is out of scope - it's backend work that monitors for a change and updates UI (through the callback) when detected.  `OnResultChangedCB` is an `Action<string?>`.  The point is notifying the UI of an update when the update occurs outside of the UI's scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the calback is from a backend process, the handler will not be invoked through the `IHandleEvent` handler defined by `ComponentBase`.
You need to call `StateHasChanged` in the handler.

Depending on the lifecycle of the caller, you may also need to remove the registration when the component is destroyed.

```cs
@implements IDisposable
@code {
    private string Result { get; set; } = "";

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        OtherCode.OnResultChangedCB += this.OnResultChanged;
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    private void OnResultChanged(string? result)
    {
            Result = newResult ?? "None";
            // May be called outsode the Synchronisation Context so switch back
            InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);  
    }

    public Void Dispose()
        {
            OtherCode.OnResultChangedCB -= this.OnResultChanged;
        }
}
```

Note : If this is Net8 make sure the page is Interactive.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly.  I do have a question: why does `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)` work, but directly invoking `StateHasChanged` does not?.

Comment: `OnResultChanged` will be called on the thread that the caller is executing on.  If that is not the *synchronisation context* then you need to call `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)`.   `InvokeAsync` switches execution to the *synchronisation context* - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/b9eaae011790c0afd86948ac3e9641a1fbd847b5/src/Components/Components/src/ComponentBase.cs#L178

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate the help.  I'd tried just StateHasChanged, but didn't know about this synchronization context.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with following code, no "statehaschanged" needed. Most likely you are lack of `@rendermode InterActiveServer`

```
    public static class OtherCode
    {

        public static event Action<string?> OnResultChangedCB;
        public static void changevalue()
        {
            OnResultChangedCB.Invoke("new value");
        }
    }
```

```
@page "/"
@rendermode InteractiveServer
<p>The current value is: @Result </p>
<button @onclick="@OtherCode.changevalue">call event</button>

@code {
    private string Result { get; set; } = "";
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        OtherCode.OnResultChangedCB += (string? newResult) => Result = newResult ?? "None";  
        base.OnInitialized();
    }
}
```

Test Result
[image]

Comment: Incorrect - The update works in your code because `StateHasChanged` is called by the button OnClick handler,  This is  invoked though the `ComponentBase` registered `IHandleEvent` which does the `StateHasChanged` call for you.